# How to use a button without code-behind

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm new to WPF so this might be an easy question. Basically I'm trying to learn what I can do without code-behind.

Development environment: Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015 Community, Started a "Blank App (Universal Windows)" project

I've learned that for a button I can

```
<Button x:Name="btn1" Content="Button" Click="btn1_Click"/>
```

and then define `btn1_Click` in code-behind. But this does not seem very straightforward sometimes. Is there a way to define button click behaviour right in the xaml, without code-behind?

I've tried:

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button x:Name="btn" FontSize="64" Content="Button">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="btn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="500"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

It compiles fine, but when I launch the app, it throws an Exception when initializing:

```
// In MainPage.xaml.cs
// This file was vs-generated. I did not modify it in any way

// In class MainPage
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent(); // Exception is thrown here
}
```

The exception says `XamlParseException`: Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.EventTrigger.RoutedEvent'. [Line: 13 Position: 31]

So what does it mean? Am I doing it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

So, this is a multi-part question.  As far as your exception is concerned:

You need to either set default `Width` for the button or set the `From` property in the `DoubleAnimation`:

```
<Button x:Name="btn" FontSize="64" Content="Button" Width="200">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="btn" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="500"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

That's because by default, `Width` is set to `Double.NaN`.

When you're talking about handling button's click event, I get a feeling you're talking about visual behavior.  Doing that in XAML is the preferred way in WPF and there are a lot of different approaches.  What you're doing with the Storyboard is fine and there are countless other approaches, because WPF is very flexible.  If you're talking about the actual C# code that has nothing to do with UI behavior, then you'll benefit from learning the MVVM pattern.

Comment: I added Width, and added <EventTrigger.Actions>, but I still get the exception

Comment: @MichaelKim Then there is some other issue in your code.  The code I pasted works perfectly for me.

Comment: I started a fresh Blank App project. MainPage.xaml is the only thing I've every edited

Answer (score 0):

XAML have built-in support for the Command Pattern.

I am using the RelayCommand in [MVVM Light toolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight/). (if you don't use MVVM Light, you can have your own concrete implementation to the interface: System.Windows.Input.ICommand)

Firstly, you can defined the behaviour after the button is clicked.

MainPage.xaml.cs (Note that in the real world, you should place the Command in a ViewModel)

```
private RelayCommand _testCommand;
public RelayCommand TestCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _testCommand
            ?? (_testCommand = new RelayCommand(
                () =>
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test Button Clicked.");
                }));
    }
}

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    // Set the object that contain the Command to the page's data context
    // Again, you should set the DataContext to the ViewModel that contain the Command
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<Button Command="{Binding TestCommand}" Content="Test Button" ></Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve some interactivity using plain XAML. But this interactivity is limited like changing visual states, animating properties, changing styles, making prototypes etc. To explore what can be done without code you can explore Expression Blend, and concepts like Behavior, DataStore, Animation(Timeline and Primitives). If you think you can write something like .... like in asp.net, then you can't.

In your code above, you have to set Width in button or use From attribute along with To.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into those concepts. But how about the exception? I added Width, didn't fix

Comment: <Button Command="{Binding HelloCommand}">Hello</Button>
                    <Button x:Name="btn" FontSize="64" Content="Button" Width="45"> ...
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="btn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"  To="500"/> ... This will work. Or you can do : <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="btn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"  From= "50" To="500"/>